# Selenium WD | A non main class, does not recognize Chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I have 2 unrelated classes

1) the first, a Main class, I pasted here as a refference. It recognizes Chrome driver very well.

2) The second, a non-main class, Does not recognize my Chrome Driver for some reason

(?) If I open any class that is not a Main, chrome driver is not recognizes inside...Why is that?

Thanks?

> Main class that works

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

//WebElement Practice 

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SocketTestsFINAL2Dublicate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\automation\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe"); 
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 


        driver.get("https://www.investing.com"); 
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[href = '/markets/']")).click();;


        // list |

        int size = 1;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i) {

            List <WebElement> list2 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[nowrap='nowrap']>a"));

            //Enter the stock page
            size = list2.size();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            list2.get(i).click();

            Thread.sleep(2000);


            // Print instrument name
            WebElement instrumentName = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='float_lang_base_1 relativeAttr']"));
            System.out.println(instrumentName.getText());

            // Check if stock is opened/closed
            WebElement Status = null;
            if (Status == driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".inlineblock.redClockBigIcon.middle.isOpenExchBig-1")));
            {
                System.out.println("Stock is closed");
                driver.navigate().back();
            }

            // Stock is opened
            if (Status == driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".inlineblock.greenClockBigIcon.middle.isOpenExchBig-1014")))
            {
                WebElement e3 = driver.findElement(By.id("last_last")); // Find Socket Element#1
                String newSocket = e3.getText(); 
                Thread.sleep(1);

                String printold = newSocket; // Old socket value for print on screen
                String lettersOnlynewSocket1 = newSocket.replaceAll("[\\W]", ""); // remove punctuations
                double CurrentSocketValue = Double.valueOf(lettersOnlynewSocket1); // !! Parsing from String to double 


                double OldSocketValue = CurrentSocketValue ;

                Thread.sleep(90000);

                WebElement e4 = driver.findElement(By.id("last_last")); //  Find Socket Element#2
                newSocket = e4.getText();
                String printNew = newSocket; // New socket value for print on screen


                String lettersOnlynewSocket2 = newSocket.replaceAll("[\\W]", ""); // remove punctuations
                CurrentSocketValue = Double.valueOf(lettersOnlynewSocket2);


                // Status is : CurrentSocket = After waiting socket upated | oldSocket = Before socket update

                if (CurrentSocketValue == OldSocketValue ) // If socket is not updated - Print 'Fail'

                    System.out.println("Socket is not updated");

                else    
                {
                    System.out.println("Socket is updated succesfully");
                }

                System.out.println("Current value is:" +printNew +"old value is:" +printold);
                driver.navigate().back();

            }



        }
    }
}
```

> But this, Non main class, does not work

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SocketNotMain {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\automation\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe"); 
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 

driver.get("https://www.investing.com"); 
driver.navigate().refresh();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[href = '/markets/']")).click();;

    public boolean isAvailable ()
    {
        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Class structure is all wrong. You need to write statements, other than initialization or declaration, inside a method in the class.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why do you initialize the chromedriver in both class?

Comment: These are 2 different classes, 

1) The first one is a main class - that recognizes the Chrome Driver
2) The second one is not a main class - that does not recognizes the Chrome driver.

* They are not related.

I am asking - If I create a non-main class, it does not recognizes my Chrome driver. Why?

Comment: @dima edunov please see the answer below and check if it is helpful. Grasshopper clarifies your wrong coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a sequence of the comment above by @Grasshopper Your non main class should be like this.

```
  public class SocketNotMain {

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\automation\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe"); 
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 

        driver.get("https://www.investing.com"); 
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[href = '/markets/']")).click();
    } 


}
```